# find nearest future date from columns

Tags: python, pandas

Please help with finding the next date from today for each row item from the four columns as show below. I have been stuck at this for a while now.

```
           InDate1     InDate2     InDate3     InDate4
284075  2018-03-07  2018-09-07  2019-03-07  2019-01-21
334627  2018-03-07  2018-09-07  2019-03-07  2019-09-07
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i would like the output to be 2019-03-07 ( next date from today:2019-01-21)its a coincidence the they are found in InDate3 , but they jumbled across the four columns .

i have tired to compare to make new columns with min () and max() and trying to compare with each of them with current date .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using lookup:

For each row, find the column that holds the closest future date:

```
import pandas as pd

s = (df.apply(pd.to_datetime)    # If not already datetime
       .apply(lambda x: (x - pd.to_datetime('today')).dt.total_seconds())
       .where(lambda x: x.gt(0)).idxmin(1))

print(s)
#284075    InDate3
#334627    InDate3
#dtype: object
```

Then lookup the values for each row:

```
df.lookup(s.index, s)
#array(['2019-03-07', '2019-03-07'], dtype=object)
```

---

To elaborate on what this does, you can look at what each part does separately

First, determine the difference in time between your `DataFrame` and today. `.apply(pd.to_datetime)` converts everything to a `datetime` so it can do arithmetic with the dates, and the second apply finds the time difference, converting it from a `timedelta` to the number of seconds, which is just a float. (Not sure why simple `df - pd.to_datetime('today')` doesn't quite work and the apply is needed)

```
s = (df.apply(pd.to_datetime)    # If not already datetime
       .apply(lambda x: (x - pd.to_datetime('today')).dt.total_seconds()))

print(s)
             InDate1       InDate2       InDate3       InDate4
284075 -2.769565e+07 -1.179805e+07  3.840347e+06 -4.765262e+04
334627 -2.769565e+07 -1.179805e+07  3.840347e+06  1.973795e+07
```

Dates in the future will have a positive time difference, so I use `.where` to find only the cells that have positive values, replacing everything else with `NaN`

```
s = s.where(lambda x: x.gt(0))
# Could use s.where(s.gt(0)) here since `s` is defined

print(s)
        InDate1  InDate2       InDate3       InDate4
284075      NaN      NaN  3.840347e+06           NaN
334627      NaN      NaN  3.840347e+06  1.973795e+07
```

Then `.idxmin(axis=1)` will return the column that has the minimum value (ignoring `NaN`), for each row (axis=1), which is the closest future date.

```
s.idxmin(1)

print(s)
284075    InDate3
334627    InDate3
dtype: object
```

Finally, [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to lookup the original date in that cell is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: hey this seems to work , can u please elaborate on the code . it would be very helpful .

Comment: @prdp13 Sure. If something is still not clear, try further splitting the steps up as I have done above, to see the output after every step.

Comment: thank u , it makes sense now and i am almost at the end of resolving the issue i had . I wanted to check if i need to replace NaT/NaN values with some value before applying those functions

Comment: i have few blank values where none of the four columns have satisfied the condition. i am getting a look up error due to this. is there a way to dropna and keep the index so that i can look up or is there any other way to go about ?

Comment: i resolved the issue by -
result=[]
for row, col in zip(s.index,s):
    try:
        result.append(df1.loc[row, col])
    except:
        result.append(np.nan)
result=pd.DataFrame({'Minvalue':result})

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

First stack date values into rows so that we can apply minimum and today comparisons.

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ["ID", "Field", "Date"]
```

Then filter data with today and find out minimum date.

```
df1 = df1[df1.Date > datetime.datetime.now()].groupby("ID").agg("min").reset_index()
```

Then pivot resulted date and before it, just assign a static value for determine as single column header instead of IntDate1..etc.

```
df1.Field = "MinValue"
df1 = df1.pivot(index="ID", columns="Field", values="Date").reset_index()
```

Finally merge minimum date value dataframe with original dataframe.

```
df = df.merge(df1, how="left")
```

Comment: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on